# how can ruby optionparser hidden password when user type

Tags: ruby, passwords, optionparser

When I use optionparser, I always type like this

```
ruby xxx.rb -u username -p password
```

but it's very dangerous everyone can see the password, I check the ruby api but can not find about hidden password, help me please

Thank you all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide your input when asking from input in a ruby program you can use the IO built in class.

```
require 'io/console'

STDIN.noecho(&:gets
```

This is directly from the ruby standard library. Use ruby docs IO class for more information. Here is the [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-noecho)

If I had time I would implement it into option parse for you but you can most likely figure it out pretty easily. If not, I will help you tomorrow.

Happy coding!